# Multiselect dropdown in angular 15

Tags: c#, angular

I have a dropdown with products as the title. There are 7 to 8 products bind dynamically in the dropdown. I want to select multiple values from the dropdown and save that in the DB. I have angular in my frontend and csharp in the backend.

I have tried several options like ng-multiselect-dropdowm but none of this is working.
This is my .html file:

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-start">
  <div class="col-sm-3 text-end">
    <label>
      Products:
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <select name="product" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="slaexclusion.productId">
      <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id">{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my .ts file:

```
  selectProduct(event) {
    const productId = event.target.value;
    const index = this.selectProd.indexOf(productId);
  
    if (index > -1) {
      // Product already selected; remove it
      this.selectProd.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      // Product not yet selected; add it
      this.selectProd.push(productId);
    }
  
    this.slaexclusion.productId = this.selectProd;
    console.log(this.selectProd);
  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Note that AngularJS (which stopped at version 1.8.3) is very different from Angular (which is now at version 15.2.4). Please [edit] your question to make it clear what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `multiple` to the select control like this:

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-start">
<div class="col-sm-3 text-end">
  <label>Products:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="product" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="slaexclusion.productId" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id"> {{product.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Another suggestion is to use `mat-select` and `mat-option` like so:

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-start">
<div class="col-sm-3 text-end">
  <label>Products:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <mat-select name="product" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="slaexclusion.productId" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id"> {{product.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used that you have suggested but still the result is not getting as expected